# How to setup keyboard for Normal mode in Evil [dvorak user]?

Tags: evil, keyboard-layout

I am using a dvorak keyboard and Evil Mode. I would like to keep the qwerty keys while in Normal mode. And wonder if there is a more efficient way than remapping everything.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169428/use-the-default-input-method-when-doing-an-incremental-search-in-evil) that looks like it takes the opposite route: setting dvorak only for the Insert mode. It looks fine for somebody who use dvorak layout only in Emacs but not enough if I have dvorak set as my keyboard for the whole OS.

Is there something similar to

```
(activate-normal-method "qwerty")
```

that I could use on an OS set to dvorak as its default keyboard?